# Retain Typescript intellisense in IntelliJ when using dynamic imports

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, code-completion, javascript-intellisense

I am writing a Lambda function using layers which requires me to have [dynamic require()](https://github.com/blmille1/aws-sam-layers-template/blob/master/lambdas/func2/func2Internal.js) depending on an environment variable.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
const axios = require(`${process.env.COMMON_LAYER || ""}axios`);
```

When testing the function locally I would then pass the `COMMON_LAYER` env variable as a path to the common layer directory's `node_modules` like so:

```
COMMON_LAYER=/path/to/common-layer/nodejs/node_modules/ node app.js
```

How do I retain Intellisense when I type `axios.` like if it were using a string literal?

[image]

I spent a lot of time researching `JSDoc` and I couldn't get it to work. I have also tried with typings and triple slash directives and it looks promising but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: such dynamic references can't be processed unfortunately, no way to make this work using static code analysis

Comment: It's ok. Thank you.